# Create a new file from commandline notepad++?

Tags: command-line, notepad++

Is it possible to use the command line to run notepad++ with new, blank file, as if ctrl+n were pressed inside notepad++?

I understand that you can add some commands like makefile or `notepad++ filename.txt` and then click "make the file" when it says "file does not exist.  But I would prefer to effectively hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> via a command at the Windows Command Line Interface (CLI).

Comment: I have confidence that you can do this with the `nppexec` plugin for Notepad++.

Comment: According to this answerer, the functionality does not yest exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245153/how-do-i-create-a-new-file-with-nppexec-in-notepad